# Flask-socketio sending payloads one at a time

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have the following Python script which is using Flask-socketio

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'P@ssw0rd'

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    payload1 = 'Connected!!!'
    payload2 = 'Doing thing 1'
    payload3 = 'Doing thing 2'
    emit('send_thing', payload1, broadcast=True)
    sleep(2)
    emit('send_thing', payload2, broadcast=True)
    sleep(2)
    emit('send_thing', payload3, broadcast=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

And here is the corresponding index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SocketIO Python</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my-div"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function init() {
      var socket = io()
      var divElement = document.getElementById('my-div')

      socket.on('send_thing', function(payload) {
        var dataElement = document.createElement('inner')
        dataElement.innerHTML = payload
        divElement.appendChild(dataElement)
      })
    })()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when a client connects, it first says 'Connected!!!' and then 2 seconds later a new 'inner' element appears that says 'Doing thing 1' followed by 2 seconds later a new 'inner' element appears that says 'Doing thing 2' etc.

But what is happening is that when a client connects, it sends all 3 lines at the same time (after 4 seconds which is both sleep statements). This is the first time using SocketIO so I'm sure I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you use eventlet or gevent, the `time.sleep()` function is blocking, it does not allow any other tasks to run.

Three ways to address this problem:

1. Use `socketio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()`.
2. Use `eventlet.sleep()` or `gevent.sleep()`.
3. Monkey patch the Python standard library so that `time.sleep()` becomes async-friendly.

Comment: I gave you three ways to address the problem. The fourth would be to not use an async framework, or in other words, drop eventlet and/or gevent. If you want to use one of these libraries, then you cannot use threading.